# Map a list to a nested list fast

Tags: python

I want to create a function which gives me the corresponding position of the element in a given nested list:

```py
nested_list = [[0,1,2], [4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10]]
```

So I want to be able to get a function that does this correspondence:

```
f(6)
#Here, nested_list[2][0] == 6
>> (2,0) 

f(2)
#Here, nested_list[2][0] == 2
>> (0,2)
```

We get a tuple with the corresponding position of an element that is searched using the function.

My current solutions it is not very elegant neither very fast:

```py
from itertools import accumulate
accum_len = list(accumulate([len(l) for l in nested_list]))

def getitem(nested_list, idx):
  # first list case
  if idx < len(nested_list[0]):
     return 0, idx
        
  # other ones in reverse order
  for i, l in enumerate(accum_len[::-1]):
     if idx >= l:
        rel_idx = idx - l
        return len(nested_list)-i, rel_idx
```

Comment: Does your nested list keep on changing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is not nested more than once, this should work:

```py
nested_list = [[0,1,2], [4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10]]
def f(n):
  return next((i,x.index(n)) for i,x in enumerate(nested_list) if n in x)

f(6)
# (2,0)

f(2)
# (0,2)
```